# libcurl certificate verification fails

Tags: curl, ssl-certificate, libcurl

I am using libcurl from C++ code but it it failing during certificate verification. Here is the error output:

errorbuffer: error setting certificate verify locations:
CAfile: /usr/share/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt
CApath: none

I don't understand why does it look for certificate in that location, I haven't specified any particular location. 
Running it in unsecure mode by using below code runs normally:

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

But I want to run it in secure mode.

Any ideas why is it looking for certificates in that wrong location?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

libcurl has a built-in default location where it looks for the CA cert bundle. That default path is set when libcurl is built. In many cases that would be done by the Linux distro maker(s).

If you want to provide a different CA cert bundle that the default, libcurl offers options to do so:

- [CURLOPT_CAINFO](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAINFO.html) sets the file name to load CA certs from
- [CURLOPT_CAPATH](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_CAPATH.html) sets the directory (for primarily OpenSSL-using libcurl versions) in which  single CA certs are stored

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I have another question. when I set certificate path like below verification passes successfully:
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt"
But I wonder is this the default location for root certificates? I mean if I add that hard coded path to my code I guess on some other machine it can not work because ca-certificates.crt root certificate may be in some other location.

Comment: That's why distro people or whoever builds libcurl is meant to make sure the correct default path is set built-in. If your application needs a specific set you should probably consider bundling it with your app. You'll find it hard to know where the default bundle is located without doing a similar search that curl's configure script is doing.

Comment: The thing is that I don't need any specific set. I need libcurl to see the default ssl root certificate, however it doesn't find it until I set explicitly to look for it in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificate.crt location. So seams that libcurl builtin default path is not correct.